# ActionScript compilation error: The name of definition 'Main' does not reflect the location of this file

Tags: actionscript-3

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong with this?

I have a movie clip called turret that is on the screen and is instanced as Turret,
I have a movie clip called bullet and that is in the library exported for AS "bullet" no quotes.

Here is the website http://wonderfl.net/c/du34

My frame (main) class is called du34

My code for du34 is:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width=1000, height=1000, framerate=24)]
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private static const SCREEN_WIDTH: int = 1000
        private static const SCREEN_HEIGHT: int = 1000

        private var turret: Turret = null
        private var me: MouseEvent = null
        private var trigger: Boolean = false

        private var bullets: Array = []

        public function Main():void 
        {
            graphics.beginFill(0x0)
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
            graphics.endFill()

            turret = new Turret(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
            turret.addEventListener(Turret.ADD_BULLET, onAddBullet)
            addChild(turret)

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame)
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(): void { trigger = true } )
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(): void { trigger = false } )
        }

        private var nextAddBullet: Bullet = null;
        private function onAddBullet(e: BulletEvent): void {
            nextAddBullet = new Bullet(turret.x + e.pos, turret.y, mouseX, mouseY)
        }

        private var frameProcessing: Boolean = false

        private function onEnterFrame(e: Event): void {
            if (frameProcessing) return
            frameProcessing = true

            if (null != nextAddBullet) {
                bullets.push(nextAddBullet)
                addChild(nextAddBullet)
                nextAddBullet = null
            }

            turret.frameAction(trigger)
            var i: int
            for (i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
                var bullet: Bullet = bullets[i]

                if (null != bullet) {
                    if (bullet.frameAction()) {
                        removeChild(bullet)
                        bullets[i] = null
                    }
                }
            }

            i = bullets.length
            while (0 < i--) {
                if (null == bullets[i]) bullets.splice(i, 1)
            }
            frameProcessing = false
        }
    }
}

import flash.events.Event
import flash.display.Sprite
import flash.geom.Point

class BulletEvent extends Event {

    private var _pos: int = 0
    public function get pos(): int { return _pos }

    public function BulletEvent(type:String, pos: int, bubbles:Boolean = false, cancelable:Boolean = false) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        _pos = pos;
    }
}

// 弾丸
class Bullet extends Sprite {
    private var t: Point
    private var d: Point

    private static const BULLET_SIZE: int = 3
    public function Bullet(_x: int, _y: int, _tx: int, _ty: int): void {
        graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF)
        graphics.drawEllipse(-BULLET_SIZE/2, -BULLET_SIZE/2, BULLET_SIZE, BULLET_SIZE)
        graphics.endFill()

        x = _x
        y = _y
        t = new Point(_tx, _ty)
        d = t.subtract(new Point(x, y))
        d.normalize(10)
        frameAction()
    }

    public function frameAction(): Boolean {
        x += d.x
        y += d.y

        var cx: Boolean = (0 <= d.x) ? t.x <= x : x <= t.x;
        var cy: Boolean = (0 <= d.y) ? t.y <= y : y <= t.y;

        return (cx && cy)
    }
}

// 砲身
class Barrel extends Sprite {

    private static const BARREL_LENGTH: int = 20

    private var _pos: int = 0
    private var _loading: int = 0
    public function get pos(): int { return _pos }
    public function loading(): Boolean { return 0 < _loading }

    public function Barrel(pos: int = 0) { _pos = pos }

    public function frameAction(): void {
        if (0 < _loading) _loading -= 2

        var d: Point = new Point(mouseX, mouseY)
        d.normalize(BARREL_LENGTH - _loading)

        graphics.clear()
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xc0c0c0)
        graphics.moveTo(_pos, 0)
        graphics.lineTo(d.x + _pos, d.y)
    }

    public function shot(): void {
        _loading = 8
    }
}

// 砲塔
class Turret extends Sprite {
    public static const ADD_BULLET: String = "addBullet"

    private static const SIZE: int = 25

    private var barrels: Array = []
    private var actionIndex: int = 0
    private var _loading: int = 0

    public function Turret(_x: int, _y: int): void {
        x = _x
        y = _y

        barrels.push(new Barrel(-3))
        barrels.push(new Barrel(0))
        barrels.push(new Barrel(+3))
        for each (var barrel: Barrel in barrels) addChild(barrel)

        var armor: Sprite = new Sprite()
        with (addChild(armor)) {
            graphics.beginFill(0xe0e0e0)
            graphics.drawEllipse(-SIZE/2, -SIZE/2, SIZE, SIZE)
            graphics.endFill()
        }
    }

    public function loading(): Boolean { return 0 < _loading }

    public function shot(): void {
        if (loading()) return

        actionIndex = (actionIndex + 1) % barrels.length
        var barrel: Barrel = barrels[actionIndex]
        if (barrel.loading()) return
        barrel.shot()
        _loading = 3;

        dispatchEvent(new BulletEvent(ADD_BULLET, barrel.pos))
    }

    public function frameAction(trigger: Boolean): void {
        if (0 < _loading) _loading -= 1

        if (trigger) shot()
        for each (var barrel: Barrel in barrels) barrel.frameAction()
    }
}
```

I keep getting the compiled error

> 5008: The name of definition 'Main' does not reflect the location of this file. Please change the definition's name inside this file, or rename the file.du34.as

Comment: Remember to use descriptive question titles. :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the advice in the error. Rename the `Main` class inside the package definition to `du34` (or whatever the AS3 file is called), or rename the file it is in to Main. [The class and filename have to match](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f93):

> ActionScript 3.0 allows you to include multiple classes in one source file, but only one class in each file can be made available to code that is external to that file. In other words, only one class in each file can be declared inside a package declaration. You must declare any additional classes outside your package definition, which makes those classes invisible to code outside that source file. **The name of the class declared inside the package definition must match the name of the source file.**

Answer (score 0):

Do you need more semicolons ? It seems a lot of semicolons are missing.
Perhaps changing the class name might help.

Comment: Semicolons are not required in ActionScript.

Comment: I have a box of semicolons in my basement that I'm not using, if you need some.

Comment: oh. Are you against putting semicolons at the end of a statement ?

Comment: Semi-colons are only "needed" if you want to have more then 1 command on the same line. semi-colon indicated new command. semi-colon should never be placed after a function call or after "{" or "}". This is the same standard that you should follow with JavaScript. This is a standard and not required just good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In actionscript under normal uses you need one class per "as" file.
The "as" file needs to be named the same as the class.
Class names should be named with a captial first letter ex:MyClass
All class files need to be included in a package.
A package structure needs to reflex the director it is in relation to the source fla/mxml files
In your sample code you supplied you have 5 classes and you need 5 "as" files
The following example assumes the package/class is in the same directory as your FLA

saved off as Main.as

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    [SWF(width=1000, height=1000, framerate=24)]
    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private static const SCREEN_WIDTH: int = 1000
        private static const SCREEN_HEIGHT: int = 1000

        private var turret: Turret = null
        private var me: MouseEvent = null
        private var trigger: Boolean = false

        private var bullets: Array = []

        public function Main():void
        {
            graphics.beginFill(0x0)
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
            graphics.endFill()

            turret = new Turret(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
            turret.addEventListener(Turret.ADD_BULLET, onAddBullet)
            addChild(turret)

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame)
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, function(): void { trigger = true } )
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, function(): void { trigger = false } )
        }

        private var nextAddBullet: Bullet = null;
        private function onAddBullet(e: BulletEvent): void
        {
            nextAddBullet = new Bullet(turret.x + e.pos, turret.y, mouseX, mouseY)
        }

        private var frameProcessing: Boolean = false

        private function onEnterFrame(e: Event): void
        {
            if (frameProcessing) return
            frameProcessing = true

            if (null != nextAddBullet) {
                bullets.push(nextAddBullet)
                addChild(nextAddBullet)
                nextAddBullet = null
            }

            turret.frameAction(trigger)
            var i: int
            for (i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++) {
                var bullet: Bullet = bullets[i]

                if (null != bullet) {
                    if (bullet.frameAction()) {
                        removeChild(bullet)
                        bullets[i] = null
                    }
                }
            }

            i = bullets.length
            while (0 < i--) {
                if (null == bullets[i]) bullets.splice(i, 1)
            }
            frameProcessing = false
        }
    }
}
```

you still need "as" files for BulletEvent, Bullet, Barrel, Turret

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. Rename the Main class inside the package definition to du34. In the directory (same location with .fla) create folder name du34 and put du34.as into it.